# How to transform query results for a better readability in pure SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

in a database, I have a column with a code number (1 to 3). Each number corresponds to a state (PATCHED = 1 - NOTPATCHED = 2 - NOTAPPLICABLE = 3 for example). These states are documented but not stored.

When I'm making a simple request like

```sql
SELECT UID, STATES FROM COMPUTERS
```

It returns something like

```
0001   1
0002   1
0003   3
0004   2
...
```

Is-there a way in pure SQL to replace states by their meaning, to obtain something with better readability like :

```
0001   PATCHED 
0002   PATCHED 
0003   NOTAPPLICABLE 
0004   NOTPATCHED 
...
```

I would like to point out again that states meaning are not stored and can't be.

Thank you very much for your help.

William

Comment: Where is the mapping `code number` to `state`-description? It would be best if this is also in the database, otherwise you would have to maintain the mapping twice...

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done with a `CASE` expression:

```sql
SELECT 
  UID, 
  CASE STATES 
    WHEN 1 THEN 'PATCHED'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'NOTPATCHED'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'NOTAPPLICABLE'
  END AS States_new
FROM COMPUTERS
```

Comment: Don't think this is a good idea unless there is no way to maintain the mapping `code number` - `state` in the database, as you do have to change the query when the mapping changes in any way (new states for example)...

Comment: The original post says `"I would like to point out again that states meaning are not stored and can't be."`

Comment: Ok, but despide from been stored in db there might be a way to share the info between application and database which would be better. BTW: I didn't downvote or anything, as this is the only solution with the data given - but wanted to state that this is definitly not what you want considering future maintainance.

Comment: I agree with you 100% :)